# $ G \cong F_{2} $?

Tags: group-theory

Consider a group , where any element has $ord(g)=2$. Could we say that $ G \cong F_{2} $? My idea was : consider all generating elements and say $g_{1} = e_{1} \dots$ am I right?

Comment: $F_2$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{F}_2$ has exactly two elements.

Comment: Consider the direct sum of copies of $F_2$.

Comment: There is no such group.

Comment: Any element except the identity (which has order $1$).

Comment: The free group on two generators contains *no* element of order $2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups $G$ such that $g^2=e$ for all $g\in G$ are exactly the $\Bbb F_2$-vector spaces (therefore much more stuff than your guess). Exercise for you is showing the crucial part of this: any such group $G$ must be abelian.

Answer (score 0):

No, let $(\Bbb Z_2,+)$, and consider for instance $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$. Every element has order two, but $G$ has four elements. More generally the product of $n$ copies of $\Bbb Z_2$ has $2^n$ elements all of them of order $2$.